# In Python/Django what steps are necessary to sanatize/escape characters of user inputted e-mails?

Tags: python, django, email

I have a Django project with a form for users to send e-mails. It works fine so far.

But I want to be sure, that users can't (accidentally) insert malicious text. I use the django integrated email system. (`django.core.mail.EmailMessage`)

Users can:

- Set subject and body text
- Select some recipients from a database

recipients from the database are constructed like this:

```
recipients_list = ['{} <{}>'.format(r[0], r[1]) for r in recipients]
```

I am worried that the names in the database contain some bad characters like commas and causing some trouble. Also I don't know if there are more things to keep in mind. Django documentation states that header-injection will be prevented. But is that all I need to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know that python has build in what I was searching for:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.formataddr

Answer (score 0):

You could use the builtin email validator, something like:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django import forms

...
recipients_list = []
for email, name in recipients:
    try:
        validate_email(email)
        # so email is valid:
        recipients_list.append(email)
    except forms.ValidationError:
        pass
```